# Database records showing on desktop version of phonegap but not on mobile phone

Tags: phonegap

I am running a desktop version of phone gap and I can access the app through the browser. I am using ajax to get mysql database records via php. This works just fine on the desktop but I have installed the phoneGap app on my mobile phone as well. I turn bluetooth on and access the app. I can access the app but the database records do not show.

This is the url I have used in the ajax:

http://localhost:8888/pmobile/www/content.php

I tried using the url from phoneGap but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the URL that you're using is on you own computer, so how are you expecting your phone to reach your computer?

You need to host your PHP web application on some publically available web hosting provider, purchase a domain name for it, and then use that URL in your PhoneGap app.

Also remember to whitelist your domain in the config.xml file of your PhoneGap app, otherwise the security feature on the mobile phone will prevent your app from connecting to your domain.

Comment: I thought that because I was using the app on my phone it was already accessing a url on my computer where the folder full of files is residing? What is the app on my phone connecting to then as like I said, the app works until I navigate to a page that is trying to pull database records. But anyway, thanks for clearing that up. So then my url would be http://somesite.com/content.php     Is that right?

Comment: Your phone cannot access anything on your computer unless you use some debug or testing tool for that purpose. The app is installed on your phone and doesn't connect to anything. Yes, the URL would be something like that.